# Move Cursor Immediately Before a Character on a Line in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim

Say I have the following:

```
text function(contents) text
```

and I wanted it to be

```
text function() text
```

Placing the cursor right after the opening parenthesis, I thought the following command would work `df)`; however, what I ended up with was the following

```
text function( text
```

So I would need someway to specify that I want the character just before the closing parenthesis, but I'm not sure how to do that. There may also be a better way to do this.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close! You need `dt)` as in `d`elete `t`ill `)`

The `f` motion places the cursor on the `)` (remember it like `f`ind)

As for the 'best' way to do it, there is at least a more general way: if the
cursor were somewhere in the middle of the `(` and `)` (or on one of them), you
can do `di)` (or equivalently `di(`) to `d`elete `i`nside `)`

If you do `da)` (or equivalently `da(`) to `d`elete `a`round `)`, you would
delete the stuff in between and including the brackets.

The same goes for `di[`, `di{`, `di<`, `di'`, `di"` etc. Using these so-called
text objects, as opposed to the `d{motion}` way, has the advantage that you can
repeat the edit on other pairs of brackets/quotes without the cursor needing to
be in precisely the same place - it just needs to be on or in between them.

In the following you could position the cursor on e.g. the 'i' of 'initial' in
the first line, do `di)` to delete the words 'some initial text', then move the
cursor to the 'e' in 'more' in the second line and just do `.` to also delete
the words 'some more text'):

```
(some initial text)

(some more text)
```

This way also works when the brackets (or quotes) are on different lines. For
example, with the cursor somewhere between the `{}`, doing `di}` will change
this:

```
function( args ) {

    body of function

}
```

to this:

```
function( args ) {
}
```